# "You both ordered drinks" or" You both ordered a drink"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

*You both ordered drinks* or  *You both ordered a drink* or in  stated differently:

*Both of you ordered a drink* or  *Both of you ordered  drinks*

should a drink be in its plural form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both singular & plural sound correct to my ear. There's a slight difference in meaning, or at least emphasis:

> You both ordered drinks.
>   Both of you ordered drinks.

These don't specify how many drinks were ordered - the possibility is left open that one or both of you ordered several drinks.

> You both ordered a drink
>   Both of you ordered a drink

Here it's pretty strongly implied that there was only one drink per person. (Especially with the latter, it could even be argued that there was a single drink which you shared. My opinion is that such an interpretation would be incorrect, but I don't have anything to support my belief.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really *disagreeing* with [Martha](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4982/you-both-ordered-drinks-or-you-both-ordered-a-drink/4983#4983), exactly; but I do believe it would be much better in this scenario to make the pluralization of *drink* agree with that of the subject(s) of the sentence.

"Both" is *plural*. Therefore I consider this sentence to be ambiguous:

### OK

> You both ordered a drink.

The reason it's ambiguous (to me) is that *both* is plural, but *drink* is singular. The above sentence *could* be interpreted to mean that, between two people, a single drink was ordered (perhaps the two decided to share).

(Martha remarked that "My opinion is that such an interpretation would be incorrect"; and I suppose this is where we are in disagreement. Personally I feel that while such an interpretation would certainly be *odd* in the context of everyday conversation, from a rigid grammatical standpoint, it would actually be the *most correct* interpretation.)

The following option is clearer:

### Better

> You both ordered drinks.

Clearly more than one drink was ordered, total. However, I have to concede that there is still some ambiguity in the above sentence since it is not entirely evident whether each individual ordered one drink or multiple drinks.

I consider this last option to be the best of all:

### Best

> Each of you ordered a drink.

Though it's surprising to many people, "each" is singular. When the subject of your sentence is "each," it is as if you are referring to every individual within the group and making the same statement in each case—something like this:

> Person 1 ordered a drink.
>
> Person 2 ordered a drink.

The above is completely unambiguous, at least when it comes to the number of drinks ordered by the individuals comprised by the word "both".

Comment: I actually like your conclusion better than either option the OP offered. Not sure I agree with you on "Both ordered a drink" being ambiguous, though. I would find ambiguity in "Both ordered the same drink", leaving it open whether it was the same instantiation of a drink, or if both drinks were instantiations of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred phrasing for the situation I think you're describing is "each of you ordered a drink."

But none of the four you listed sound wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

The first way can mean multiple drinks, the second a single drink each.